# Difference between Object[] and Array of specific Objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I know this may be trivial but I could not find an answer yet.

What are the differences between and Object[] and an array of specific Objects, for example

```
class car {
    public Object[] someCars;
    public car[] someOthercars;
}
```

I know that car[] can store car Objects and Object[] can store any Objects. But APART from this are there any not so obvious differences?

Comment: What is the difference between an `Object` and `Car` variable ?

Comment: `Object[]` can contain any `Object`s. `car[]` can contain instances of `car`. As you might expect.

Comment: Open a book before you ask.

Comment: @khelwood. So the only difference is that Object[] can contain any objects while car[] can only store car objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's Object Oriented Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467631/whats-object-oriented-programming)

Comment: @AntonHlinisty It's not a duplicate. I understand the basics of OO programming. Just wanted to know if there are some not so obvious differences between Object[] and Arrays of certains types of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Car[]` can contain only `Car` instances, or sub-classes of `Car` instances.
If you were to have a class like this: `class Honda extends Car` , `Honda` instances can be populated in the `Car` array as well, because Honda **extends** from `Car`.

`Object[]` can contain any `Object` instances, or any subclass of `Object` (every class in Java is a subclass `Object`, **even if it is not explicitly stated** with an `extends` keyword in a custom class), so any instance in java can be populated in the `Object` array.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions are given here:

1. [The Java™ Tutorials. Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)
2. [The Java™ Tutorials. Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)

**UPD**

`Car` class inherits from `Object`. An array of `Car`s is narrower than an array of `Object`s. So roughly speaking if you store your cars in an array of objects - you will need to cast them back to cars each time you want to use an instance. I doubt that you really need that.

Comment: Don't see any reference to Object Arrays within your link

Comment: @CuriousIndeed, see the `What Is Inheritance?` at the second link. Consider that `Car` implicitly inherits from `Object`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21826003)

Comment: @BoarGules added textual explanation